# Display data from access using dataset

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\Blessing\Documents\Ishvatest.mdb"
    con.Connectionstring = dbProvider & dbSource
    con.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * From Employees"
    da = New OleDb.OleDBDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Ishvatest")
    MsgBox("Ishvatest is now open")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Ishvatest is now closed")
    txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtID.Name = ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

If I run the program with this code I get the error "Null Reference Exception was unhandled"

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception message?

Answer (score 1):

Well, supposing that the table is not empty, then the problems is probably here

```
da.Fill(ds, "Ishvatest")
```

Here you file a dataset and names its first table with the name "Ishvatest", but then you try to read from a table called "Employees". There is no table with that name

Change to (or da.Fill(ds, "Employees"))

```
txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Ishvatest").Rows(0).Item(1)
txtID.Name = ds.Tables("Ishvatest").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

Another solution could be to use an index to refer to the datatable instead of the name and (as an added precaution) checking also if you have any record to read

```
If ds.Tables.Count > 0 AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    txtID.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtID.Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is *always* the same thing. Something is nothing. <strike>The first one would be that you don't assign anything to `con` before using it, hence it's `null`;</strike> Others could well occur if you get past that point.

The bottom line is that you need to assign something to an instance prior to using it (when a reference type). So, `con` needs to be a `New OleDbConnection()`. Or, you need to make sure it is something before using it (if something is returned, for instance, such as with `ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0)`: is there a row?)

Comment: @Steve Hm, it's not _literally_; the `As New` threw me off. In that case, the issue is the same, something is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 da.Fill(ds, "Ishvatest")
```

And trying to bind your data to "Employees"!!!

```
   txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtID.Name = ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

It should have been

```
txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Ishvatest").Rows(0).Item(1)
txtID.Name = ds.Tables("Ishvatest").Rows(0).Item(2)
```

Or you should fill dataset as follow :

```
da.Fill(ds, "Employees")
```

And use

```
   txtID.Text = ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0).Item(1)
   txtID.Name = ds.Tables("Employees").Rows(0).Item(2)
```