# Add Multiple Databases in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, oledb

Is it possible to connect multiple databases to a program?

I added a database, but it was always through the "Data Source Config Wizard". My application deals with one main database, but I need to load information from other databases and add it to the main one (the user will select which database through the OpenFileDialog).

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TblTestBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblTestBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblTestBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TestdbDataSet)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TestdbDataSet.tblTest' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblTestTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestdbDataSet.tblTest)

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
        Dim DBConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        '''' Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

        Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        'Dim dbSource As String = opnFile.ShowDialog()
        opnFile.ShowDialog()
        Dim ex As String = opnFile.FileName
        MessageBox.Show(ex)

        Dim dbSource As String = "DataSource=" & ex
        MessageBox.Show(dbSource, "Data Source String", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)


        Dim DBDataSet As New DataSet
        '''' Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim DBDataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        '''' Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        DBConnection.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        'DBDataAdapter = (sql, DBConnection)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also, can someone explain to me the link in DataAdapter, DataConnection, and the DataSet? From what I see, the DataConnection is just the link that will connect the application to the database. The DataSet is your actual data from the database. So what is the DataAdapter for?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the database is from Microsoft Access!

Answer (score 0):

You can add several databases using the Database wizard. You will be missing the binding navigator but you can get this easily by creating a temporary form in your project add the database to this then just copy over the binding navigator before deleting the temp form.

Comment: But let's say the program wasn't in Visual Studio. Is it possible to do it through code? Any extra databases will be loaded through the program, not through the wizard (since the extra databases will be loaded in from users)

Comment: Yes you will need to hard code the Databases into your program. You will need to build a SQL Query and lets say you have textbox with the location of the DB include this as a string that you are going to use to Query your DB.

Comment: Hardcode in the sense that I cannot let users add information from other databases? I have the "main" database hardcoded, I'm just wondering how I can add the data from other databases onto the main one.

Comment: No I mean hard code as in you will have to write the SQL functions and will not be software generated by the wizard.

Comment: I can write the SQL functions... but I'm still a bit confused on binding the database itself. As previously stated, I have my "main" database binded to my program. I just need to load values from other databases and store them in my main one.

Comment: Ok then load your into a datatabe and query the table before taking your result.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread [Display data from access using dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311819/display-data-from-access-using-dataset) The use the following.

Try something like this after you load your table into a Dataset

```
For Each row1 In (From dr As DataRow In yourDataSet.Tables(0).Rows Select dr Where dr("Column_Name").ToString.StartsWith(yourstring)

somestring = row1("Column_Name").ToString
```